# How do I implement FromStr with a concrete lifetime?

Tags: rust

I want to implement `FromStr` for a struct with a lifetime parameter:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> FromStr for Foo<'a> {
    type Err = ();
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Foo<'a>, ()> {

        Ok(Foo { bar: s })
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let foo: Foo = "foobar".parse().unwrap();
}
```

However, the compiler complains:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:11:12
   |
11 |         Ok(Foo { bar: s })
   |            ^^^
   |
help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn from_str(s: &'a str) -> Result<Foo<'a>, ()>
  --> src/main.rs:9:5
   |
9  |     fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Foo<'a>, ()> {
   |     ^
```

Changing the impl to

```
impl<'a> FromStr for Foo<'a> {
    type Err = ();
    fn from_str(s: &'a str) -> Result<Foo<'a>, ()> {
        Ok(Foo { bar: s })
    }
}
```

gives this error

```
error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/main.rs:9:5
   |
9  |     fn from_str(s: &'a str) -> Result<Foo<'a>, ()> {
   |     ^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&str) -> std::result::Result<Foo<'a>, ()>`
   = note:    found type `fn(&'a str) -> std::result::Result<Foo<'a>, ()>`
note: the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 9:51...
  --> src/main.rs:9:52
   |
9  |     fn from_str(s: &'a str) -> Result<Foo<'a>, ()> {
   |                                                    ^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 9:51
  --> src/main.rs:9:52
   |
9  |     fn from_str(s: &'a str) -> Result<Foo<'a>, ()> {
   |                                                    ^
help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn from_str(s: &'a str) -> Result<Foo<'a>, ()>
  --> src/main.rs:9:5
   |
9  |     fn from_str(s: &'a str) -> Result<Foo<'a>, ()> {
   |     ^
```

[Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ed5c4813d25ce241e2b60e63ff2033b0&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Is there a reason to not just make this a constructor?

Comment: Yes, I use it in a parser, where I only hold references in order not do any copies

Comment: This is the same issue as I dealt with at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24575591/497043; it's not possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't believe that you can implement `FromStr` in this case.

```
fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, <Self as FromStr>::Err>;
```

There's nothing in the trait definition that ties the lifetime of the input to the lifetime of the output.

**Not a direct answer**, but I'd just suggest making a constructor that accepts the reference:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a str
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new(s: &str) -> Foo {
        Foo { bar: s }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::new("foobar"); 
}
```

This has the side benefit of there not being any failure modes - no need to `unwrap`.

You could also just implement `From`:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Foo<'a> {
    fn from(s: &'a str) -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo { bar: s }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let foo: Foo = "foobar".into();
}
```

Comment: **Why** doesn't `FromStr` support this? Is there a good reason to disallow values returned from `FromStr::from_str` from referencing the input?

Comment: @RBF06 "because that's the way it was written" is the most accurate answer. That is just what most usages of `FromStr` were and now it's stable.