# &str String and lifetime

Tags: rust

I am working on a small lexer in Rust. I had the idea of putting the lexing phase into the implementation of the `Iterator` trait.

```
struct Lexer {
    text: String
}

impl Iterator for Lexer {
    ...
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<LexItem>{
        ....
        // slicing issue
        self.text = self.text[i .. self.text.len()]

    }
}
```

I have not quite grokked lifetime management here completely. I would be fine by defining the struct with a lifetime for the `text` attribute which would (probably) make the subslicing more easy. Yet I fail to incorporate such a lifetime in my code. On the other hand, I have a hard time converting the slice `self.text[i .. .....]` into a `String` again (dunno if that is possible).

### What I tried:

I tried the following modification:

```
struct Lexer<'a> {
    text: &'a str
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Lexer<'a> {
    ...
    fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<LexItem>{
        ....
        // slicing issue
        self.text = self.text[i .. self.text.len()]

    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
src/lexer.rs:64:5: 81:6 error: method `next` has an incompatible type for trait: expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime [E0053]
```

the other implementation I tried

```
impl<'a> Iterator for Lexer<'a> {
    ...
    fn next<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Option<LexItem>{
        ....
        // slicing issue
        self.text = self.text[i .. self.text.len()]

    }
}
```

```
src/lexer.rs:66:21: 66:52 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&'a str`,
    found `str`
(expected &-ptr,
    found str) [E0308]
src/lexer.rs:66         self.text = self.text[i .. self.text.len()];
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I figure that something like this should work, as I would work with subslices only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(By the way: `foo[i..foo.len()]` should always be equivalent to `foo[i..]`.)

The type of `self.text[i..]` is the unsized type `str` if `self.text` is of type `String` or `&str`. In order to make it sized (thus, in order to make it work), you need to turn it into the same type as `text`.

If `text` is `String`, this could be done by calling `.to_string()` on the result of the slicing; a reference will automatically be taken, making it legal. Thus, `self.text = self.text[i..].to_string();`. ([`std::borrow::ToOwned::to_owned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_owned) could also be used and would be slightly more efficient.)

If `text` is `&str`, just prefix the slicing operation with `&`, making it take a reference as is needed: `self.text = &self.text[i..];`.

For the whole lifetime matter, please read my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24575591/497043; it explains your problems with `fn next(&'a mut self)` and so forth.

It looks to me like you want the whole thing to be based around string slices (`&str`) rather than owned strings (`String`). The former works for iterators (see the aforementioned answer) while the latter does not.

Comment: You mention _"std::borrow::ToOwned::to_owned could also be used and would be slightly more efficient."_; mind elaborating on why would it be slightly more efficient? OTOH, which one of `to_string()`/`to_owned()` would be more idiomatic in this case?

Comment: `.to_string()` uses the `std::fmt` infrastructure, which is comparatively heavy. On simple cases like a string it should now optimise away fully at runtime (this was not *quite* true when I wrote the answer), but there are certain slight variants that you can form which won’t optimise away perfectly, and there’s still a little compile-time overhead too. I myself would probably most commonly write `String::from(text)` these days, but I wouldn’t blink at `text.to_string()`.