# "error: mismatched types" when indexing a &str

Tags: rust

I have a `struct MyStruct<'a>` where `self.text` is of type `&'a str`

I assumed that this would give me a substring of this str:

```
let slice: &str  = self.text[i .. self.text.len()];
```

However I get the following error:

```
src/lexer.rs:67:28: 67:59 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&str`,
    found `str`
(expected &-ptr,
    found str) [E0308]
src/lexer.rs:67         let slice: &str  = self.text[i .. self.text.len()];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [&str String and lifetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999226/str-string-and-lifetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.text[i .. self.text.len()]` is of type `str`; you need to re-borrow the result to get a `&str`.  Also note that you can omit the upper bound on the range.  That gets you:

```
let slice: &str = &self.text[i..];
```

**Edit**: To note the *why*: this is because slicing is just a special case of indexing, which behaves the same way (if you want a borrowed reference to the thing you've indexed, you need to borrow from it).  I can't really get into more detail without going into Dynamically Sized Types, which is perhaps best left for a different discussion.