# Using self in Iterator

Tags: rust

Suppose I have the following structs:

```
pub struct Foo {
    pub i: i32
}

pub struct Bar<'a> {
    pub foo: &'a Foo
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn make_baz(&self) -> Baz {
        Baz { bar: self }
    }
}

pub struct Baz<'a, 'b: 'a> {
    pub bar: &'a Bar<'b>
}
```

Is it possible to impl an Iterator like:

```
impl<'a> Iterator for Bar<'a> {

    // how do I get this lifetime in here?
    type Item = Baz<_, 'a>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(self.make_baz())
    }
}
```

Comment: Short version: No, you cannot return a reference based on `self` as part of the `Iterator` trait. [Another question with good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30422177/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster, okay, thanks for the links!