# How do you index select over a matrix in Rust

Tags: matrix, rust

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
pub struct Matrix<T> {
    pub grid: Vec<T>,
}

/// constructor
impl<T> Matrix<T> {
    pub fn new(data: Vec<T>) -> Matrix<T> {
        Matrix { grid: data }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to do something like this, something close to the `iloc` of Python's pandas if you know what that is ([Pandas Cheat sheet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf)):

```
// m equals a matrix of type Vec<String>
// the matrix is 11 rows 4 columns. I dont want the first row
// because of headers or the first or last column.
// args {cols: Vec<?>||tuple(i64,str,i64), rows: Vec<?>||tuple(i64,str,i64}
let data = m.extract(vec![1,2], (-1,':',))
```

I have looked at those other libraries and they are great for what they do but I am working on something that these libraries do not accomplish.

The arguments for the extraction is `columns, rows`, which I would like to take either a tuple or Vec, but if that is not possible I will settle for a vector. As stated this syntax is derived from python's pandas library which I posted a link to the cheat sheet with reference to the `iloc` function. So `vec![1,2]` would return me only columns 1 and 2 with index starting at 0. While for the tuple `(-1,':',)`, I would want to return all rows except the first. So if instead it was `(,':',-1)` I would get all the rows except the last. `(1,':',6)` would return rows 1-6 including all in between. `(,':',)` would return all rows. Which `(0,':',0)` and `vec![0]` both give only the first row/column except the vector type cannot specify a range.

As for the data structure I want to return is a Matrix like the ones used in the other matrix libraries. A matrix type with rows, columns and data. I am reading in a csv file into a generic Matrix T which I should probably turn into just a String since I doubt I will ever change that. I need to be able to convert the data int the String matrix into f64 and then have a new matrix type hold that to work matrices math on. I still need to keep the `String` matrix as a reference to create my own logic to communicate positive or negative feedback(true/false) on fields that contain things like country names by a match or with yes/no in columns.

How would I iterate over this matrix which will contain a `Vec<Vec<T>>` to retrieve a specific matrix from it? I have headers, and I want all the data so I need to skip the index of `Matrix.grid[0]` but none else.

Do I need to write an `impl Iterator` and if so how would this be done? I have seen [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422177/lifetime-in-iterator-impl) with a different format but do I need lifetimes to accomplish this? Is there anything I need to add the the struct or with a `impl` to get the capability to copy, get a `mut ref` to all values, a `ref` to all values?

I am rather new to Rust and am very eager to learn more. I have read the whole Rust book, taken a course online, but still I find myself lost when dealing with a Matrix.

Comment: Your `extract` example code doesn't even have balanced delimiters, much less explain what the arguments even **mean**. How are we supposed to know what `(-1,':',)` is supposed to communicate? What kind of data structure do you expect this to return and what operations are you going to perform on that result? It would be trivial to write a version of `extract` that just panics, but I doubt that is your goal. Overall, your question appears far too underspecified to attempt to answer here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The best suggestion I have for you is to go look at the source of [one of the numerous matrix libraries](https://crates.io/search?q=matrix). You may also have better luck asking such an open-ended question on a resource like [the Rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/), the [users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/), or the [Rust IRC channels](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/community.html).

Comment: Re: "delimiters" — I meant the missing close parenthesis, which you've since fixed. There's also no need to add **EDIT** text; just *edit* the question to make it better. If you address my comments, I delete them, so there's no point in referring to them ;-)