# How to resolve expected `:`, found keyword `self`?

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm learning to write iterators in Rust but am hitting an "expected colon" issue where I would not expect a colon to even make sense. Maybe it has to do with lifetimes? References? I tried making a regular function that returns the same data in the same way and it worked (or at least got past this error message) so it appears to be special to the `Iterator` trait... but I can't work out why.

```rust
struct LogEntry;

pub struct LogIter<'a> {
    index0: bool,
    first: LogEntry,
    iter: ::std::slice::Iter<'a, LogEntry>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for LogIter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a LogEntry;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.index0 = false;
        match self.index0 {
            true => Some(&'a self.first),
            false => self.iter.next(),
        }
    }
}
```

It is meant to return `first` and then iterate normally but I cannot figure out why or how I could possibly fit a colon in here.

```
error: expected `:`, found keyword `self`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:30
   |
14 |             true => Some(&'a self.first),
   |                              ^^^^ expected `:`
```

Comment: What resources did you follow that led you to think that `&'a self.first` is valid syntax?

Comment: _Ooh..._ So that's something that led me astray. Thank you, I must have been generalizing from type signatures. Okay, so in that case what I needed to figure out is how to disambiguate lifetimes so Rust can infer the correct one. (I now get, `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *question* is solved by pointing out that `&'a foo` isn't a valid expression. It doesn't make sense to specify a lifetime when taking a reference as the compiler will automatically ensure the correct lifetimes.

You want to use `Some(&self.first)`.

---

Your *problem* is addressed by [How do I write an iterator that returns references to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30422177/155423).