# Iterate through a whole file one character at a time

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm new to Rust and I'm struggle with the concept of lifetimes. I want to make a struct that iterates through a file a character at a time, but I'm running into issues where I need lifetimes. I've tried to add them where I thought they should be but the compiler isn't happy. Here's my code:

```
struct Advancer<'a> {
    line_iter: Lines<BufReader<File>>,
    char_iter: Chars<'a>,
    current: Option<char>,
    peek: Option<char>,
}

impl<'a> Advancer<'a> {
    pub fn new(file: BufReader<File>) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let mut line_iter = file.lines();
        if let Some(Ok(line)) = line_iter.next() {
            let char_iter = line.chars();

            let mut advancer = Advancer {
                line_iter,
                char_iter,
                current: None,
                peek: None,
            };

            // Prime the pump. Populate peek so the next call to advance returns the first char
            let _ = advancer.next();

            Ok(advancer)
        } else {
            Err(anyhow!("Failed reading an empty file."))
        }
    }

    pub fn next(&mut self) -> Option<char> {
        self.current = self.peek;
        if let Some(char) = self.char_iter.next() {
            self.peek = Some(char);
        } else {
            if let Some(Ok(line)) = self.line_iter.next() {
                self.char_iter = line.chars();
                self.peek = Some('\n');
            } else {
                self.peek = None;
            }
        }

        self.current
    }

    pub fn current(&self) -> Option<char> {
        self.current
    }

    pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<char> {
        self.peek
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let file = File::open("input_file.txt")?;
    let file_buf = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut advancer = Advancer::new(file_buf)?;

    while let Some(char) = advancer.next() {
        print!("{}", char);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

And here's what the compiler is telling me:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `line`
  --> src/main.rs:37:13
   |
25 |             let char_iter = line.chars();
   |                             ---- `line` is borrowed here
...
37 |             Ok(advancer)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0597]: `line` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:49:34
   |
21 | impl<'a> Advancer<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
49 |                 self.char_iter = line.chars();
   |                 -----------------^^^^--------
   |                 |                |
   |                 |                borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 assignment requires that `line` is borrowed for `'a`
50 |                 self.peek = Some('\n');
51 |             } else {
   |             - `line` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0515, E0597.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
error: could not compile `advancer`.
```

Comment: Why do you have a `BufReader<&'a File>`? If I'm not mistaken, only `BufReader<File>` implements  `BufRead`.

Comment: @nnnmmm I took out the borrow but I still have the issues with lifetimes. I updated the code with the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- The [Chars iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.chars) borrows from the String it was created from. So you can't drop the String while the iterator is alive. But that's what happens in your `new()` method, the `line` variable owning the `String` disappears while the iterator referencing it is stored in the struct.
- You could also try storing the current line in the struct, then it would live long enough, but [that's not an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422177/how-do-i-write-an-iterator-that-returns-references-to-itself) – a struct cannot hold a reference to itself.
- Can you make a char iterator on a String that doesn't store a reference into the String? Yes, probably, for instance by storing the current position in the string as an integer – it shouldn't be the index of the char, because chars can be more than one byte long, so you'd need to deal with the underlying bytes yourself (using e.g. [`is_char_boundary()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.str.html#method.is_char_boundary) to take the next bunch of bytes starting from your current index that form a char).
- Is there an easier way? Yes, if performance is not of highest importance, one solution is to make use of `Vec`'s [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator) instance (which uses `unsafe` magic to create an object that hands out parts of itself) :

```rust
let char_iter = file_buf.lines().flat_map(|line_res| {
    let line = line_res.unwrap_or(String::new());
    line.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>()
});
```

Note that just returning `line.chars()` would have the same problem as the first point.

You might think that String should have a similar `IntoIterator` instance, and I wouldn't disagree.