# Iterate mutably over &[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] to receive `&mut [1,4,7]` then `&mut [2,5,8]` then `&mut[3,6,9]`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to iterate over a slice broken into chunks, and return a tuple with the nth element of each chunk.

Example:

`&[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I'd like to break this into chunks of size 3, and then iterate over the results, returning these tuples, one on each next() call:

`&mut[1,4,7], &mut[2,5,8], &mut[3,6,9]`

**I know that for general stuff it isn't possible to return mutable stuff, mut this is clearly disjoint, and without unsafe code we can have the `ChunksMut` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.ChunksMut.html) iterator, so maybe there's a way!**. For example, I can have 3 `ChunksMut` and then the compiler knows that the elements returned from them are disjoint.

This is my try for non mutable:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cfa7ca0bacbe6f1535050cd7dd5c537c

**PS: I want to avoid Vec or any allocation on each iteration**

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b2f7401f724928ca2ad61075c7592fc but really just call `slice.chunks(chunk_size)` directly no need for such shortcut

Comment: @Stargateur, I think the output that the OP expected is &[1,4,7], &[2,5,8], &[3,6,9], instead of &[1,2,3], &[4,5,6], &[7,8,9].

Comment: oh... well... well... impossible to do what op want without GaTs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write an iterator that returns references to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422177/how-do-i-write-an-iterator-that-returns-references-to-itself)

Comment: best I can give you without nightly https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e461ea07a4774b995353eb91deddc09d

Comment: I think it might make sense to give us a bit more surrounding context. Do you really require your iterator to return elements of type `&[T]` (i.e. slices)? If so, you probably won't get around rearranging the elements (or packing them into a `Vec`) so that they lie contiguously in memory. If not, there may be a better alternative (e.g. using a combination of `skip` and `step_by`). Is the input to your iterator always a slice? Could you possibly reorder that slice so that after reordering you can simply use `chunks`?

Comment: @Rafaelo It is not possible to get a mutable view using a shared reference without invoking undefined behaviour. If you do not have a mutable reference to the original array/slice or the ownership of it; you can't achieve what you want without copying all the elements to a new memory, though this memory doesn't have to be on the heap. Also note that the [`slice.chunks_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_mut) method requires a mutable reference to the slice but you have a shared reference: `&[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

Answer (score 4):

> so I always return a reference to its internal slice

The `Iterator` trait doesn't support this, because its contract allows the caller to extract several values and use all of them. For example, the following is permitted by `Iterator` but wouldn't be supported by your implementation:

```
// take two values out of the iterator
let a = it.next().unwrap();
let b = it.next().unwrap();
```

What you need is a "lending iterator" (also known as "streaming iterator"), see e.g. [this crate](https://docs.rs/streaming-iterator/0.1.5/streaming_iterator/). Writing lending iterators will become much easier once [GATs are stabilized](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/08/03/GATs-stabilization-push.html), but they still won't be supported by `std::iter::Iterator`.

Using the standard `Iterator` you can avoid allocation by using [`ArrayVec`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.7.2/arrayvec/struct.ArrayVec.html) or equivalent replacement for `Vec`, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69997442/iterate-over-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-to-receive-1-4-7-then-2-5-8-then/70007966#comment123737479_69997442) by @Stargateur.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you wanted to get mutable references into the original slice using the iterator, resulting in `&mut [&mut 1, &mut 4, &mut 7], &mut [&mut 2, &mut 5, &mut 8], &mut [&mut 3, &mut 6, &mut 9]`.

Without allocation / unsafe / external crates. Requires rust version 1.55 or greater:

```rust
fn iter_chunks<T, const CHUNK_SIZE: usize>(
    slice: &mut [T],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = [&mut T; CHUNK_SIZE]> + '_ {
    assert_eq!(slice.len() % CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
    let len = slice.len();
    let mut a: [_; CHUNK_SIZE] = array_collect(
        slice
            .chunks_mut(len / CHUNK_SIZE)
            .map(|iter| iter.iter_mut()),
    );
    (0..len / CHUNK_SIZE).map(move |_| array_collect(a.iter_mut().map(|i| i.next().unwrap())))
}

/// Builds an array from the first `N` items of an iterator
///
/// Panics:
///
/// If there are less then `N` items in the iterator
fn array_collect<T, const N: usize>(mut iter: impl Iterator<Item = T>) -> [T; N] {
    let a: [(); N] = [(); N];
    a.map(|_| iter.next().unwrap())
}
```

Without allocation, using an external crate:

We need to use `arrayvec` since Rust's array cannot be used with `collect`.

```rust
use arrayvec::ArrayVec;

fn main() {
    let slice = &mut [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    for (i, chunk) in iter_chunks::<_, 3>(slice).enumerate() {
        println!("{:?}", chunk);
        for t in chunk {
            *t = i;
        }
    }
    println!("slice: {:?}", slice);
}

fn iter_chunks<T, const CHUNK_SIZE: usize>(
    slice: &mut [T],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = ArrayVec<&mut T, CHUNK_SIZE>> + '_ {
    let len = slice.len();
    let mut a: ArrayVec<_, CHUNK_SIZE> = slice
        .chunks_mut(len / CHUNK_SIZE)
        .map(|chunk| chunk.iter_mut())
        .collect();
    (0..len / CHUNK_SIZE).map(move |_| {
        a.iter_mut()
            .map(|iter| iter.next().unwrap())
            .collect::<ArrayVec<_, CHUNK_SIZE>>()
    })
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
slice: [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Indeed, but this example uses allocation on every iteration, which I was trying to avoid

Comment: then just save all the mutable references to 1 vector, reorder them, and use `chunks_mut` on it.

Comment: Edited the answer to use 1 allocation only. If you want them to be slices, you need at least 1 allocation. If you just need an iterator with that ordering, I'm not sure.

Comment: unfortunately this is intended to be used for really large arrays so reallocating a large vector just to iterate over it would be really expensive

Comment: An allocation of `chunk_size` is okay?

Comment: yes, but if only once. chunk_size is 3 in this example but very likely never more than 20. I was trying without it but if needed then ok

Comment: Edited it with no allocation

Comment: Unfortunately delegating it to another crait is just delegating unsafe code for other people. I was trying to do it without external crates. I'm really sorry you've put effort into it

Comment: @Rafaelo You should make it clear in the question that you want an answer without any unsafe and any external crates. Rust is a language with a minimal standard library, and that supports unsafe for good reasons, so neither constraint is self-evident.

Comment: Added the no-unsafe no-alloc no-dependency version