# Are there any rust functions for wrapping an iterator that is dependent on a reference so the wrapper contains the referent?

Tags: rust, iterator, unsafe, standard-library

In this case I want to read integers from standard input such that they are separated by spaces **and** newline. My first attempt was similar to [the following code:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e7708e3632eb0a3a01da53d4b402632)

```
fn splitter(x: String) -> impl Iterator<Item=&'static str> {
    x.as_str().split_whitespace()
}

fn valuereader<A: std::str::FromStr>() -> impl Iterator<Item=A> 
where <A as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug
{
    let a = std::io::stdin().lines();
    let b = a.map(Result::unwrap);
    let c = b.flat_map(splitter);
    c.map(|x|x.parse().expect("Not an integer!"))
}

fn main() {
    let temp: Vec<usize> = valuereader().collect();
    println!("{:?}", temp);
}
```

The problem is that `split_whitespace` wants a `&str`, but `std::io::stdin().lines()` returns an owned `String`. I don't want to use `x.as_str().split_whitespace().collect()`, because I don't want to allocate a temporary vector.

The best solution I could come up with was to use a wrapper that contains the owned `String` and the iterator that depends on the `String`, using unsafe code.  The wrapper's implementation of `Iterator` is simply a wrapper for the iterator that depends on the `String`. [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3b94adc2c220f0810ee778647fa1fae) was the result:

```
mod move_wrapper {
    use std::pin::Pin;
    pub fn to_wrapper<'b, A: 'b, F, B: 'b> (a: A, f: F) -> Wrapper<A,B>
    where
        F: FnOnce (&'b A) -> B
    {
        let contained_a = Box::pin(a);
        // Here is the use of unsafe. It is necessary to create a reference to a that can live as long as long as needed.
        // This should not be dangerous as no-one outside this module will be able to copy this reference, and a will live exactly as long as b inside Wrapper.
        let b = f(unsafe{&*core::ptr::addr_of!(*contained_a)});
        Wrapper::<A,B> {_do_not_use:contained_a, dependent:b}
    }

    pub struct Wrapper<A,B> {
        _do_not_use: Pin<Box<A>>,
        dependent: B
    }

    impl<A,B: Iterator> Iterator for Wrapper<A,B>
    {
        type Item = B::Item;
        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
            self.dependent.next()
        }
    }
}

fn splitter(x: String) -> impl Iterator<Item=&'static str> {
    move_wrapper::to_wrapper(x, |a|a.as_str().split_whitespace())
}

fn valuereader<A: std::str::FromStr>() -> impl Iterator<Item=A> 
where <A as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug
{
    let a = std::io::stdin().lines();
    let b = a.map(Result::unwrap);
    let c = b.flat_map(splitter);
    c.map(|x|x.parse().expect("Not an integer!"))
}

fn main() {
    let temp: Vec<usize> = valuereader().collect();
    println!("{:?}", temp);
}
```

Now to the actual question. How would you do this as idiomatic as possible, if possible without using any unsafe code (does the function here called `to_wrapper` exist)? Have I written safe unsafe code? Is there any way to make my `Wrapper` work for all traits, not just `Iterator`?

**EDIT**

To be clearer, this question is about creating a method you can apply anytime you have to give ownership to something that wants a reference, not about how to read from standard input and parse to integers.

Comment: Unsafe code refers to code within an `unsafe` context, that is, code that has been explicitly marked unsafe. All this to say that there is no "risk" of accidentally writing unsafe code.

Comment: @jthulhu Did I say it is any risk I accidentally write unsafe code?  In this case I have done it deliberately. The question is if I have managed to do it in a safe way.

Comment: The `unsafe` in your code is hard to spot. You should at the least have `// SAFETY` comment explaining why you think it's sound.

Comment: BTW: `lines()` is slow because it has to allocate a new `String` for each line, it's better to use `read_line` directly. But of course, then you can't use `Iterator`.

Comment: @PitaJ: Though the OP may still want to do that; if they're so concerned with performance that `x.as_str().split_whitespace().collect()` is objectionable due to allocating a temporary `Vec`, presumably the allocation activity for a `String` per line is also an issue. Mind you, this is almost certainly premature optimization; even on the fastest modern hard drives, I/O would almost certainly swamp any allocator overhead, so I'd just do the convenient thing until I had evidence it was causing problems.

Comment: `x.as_str().split_whitespace().collect()` wouldn't work either, because the slices would be referencing the `String` that's dropped at the end of `splitter`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The reason I am doing it the more complicated way is because I am learning rust and want to get some experience of the most idiomatic methods. In this case it may not be much more efficient, but in other cases the difference may be more prominent. Then the experience is really useful.

Comment: @PitaJ `x.as_str().split_whitespace().map(|a|a.to_owned()).collect()` would work.

Comment: Sure but that's just adding allocations, a `String` for each number. It would be better to just do the parsing there instead.

Comment: Messing around with lazy iterators like this is fun, but if you're just going to `collect` in the end, just do everything eagerly: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9c89d84cc6d81ce1225621fb1173c07)

Comment: @PitaJ One reason not to do it that way is if you are going to read multiple lines of input several times. I am not sure if this will work if you change how the buffering of the terminal works, but there may be some use-cases: `let temp: Vec<usize> = valuereader().take(10).collect();` and then `let temp2: Vec<usize> = valuereader().collect();`. But you would probably do it the way you did it if you actually had to read several lines of integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create self-referential types in safe rust, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/6274355). Unfortunately, fixing this issue still leaves the next one.

Iterators that return items that can't outlive the iterator are impossible, [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30422177/6274355). Yours is even more restrictive: it's trying to create items that can't exist by the time the next item is fetched, which means you need a [lending iterator](https://docs.rs/lending-iterator/latest/lending_iterator/) to make this in its current state.

It would be quite easy to create your `Vec` with some nested for loops:

```rs
fn valuereader<A: FromStr>() -> Vec<A>
where
    A::Err: Debug,
{
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    for line in std::io::stdin().lines() {
        for word in line.unwrap().split_whitespace() {
            let a = word.parse().unwrap();
            v.push(a);
        }
    }
    v
}
```

However, this is not very instructive, and creates many temporary allocations, especially if you only need an iterator and not a `Vec`.

In order to make your original idea work idiomatically, you need an iterator that produces owned items. Fortunately, your final item type is `usize` (or anything that comes out of `parse`, which has to be owned), so you can create an iterator that creates those. This only allocates one `String`, which will grow to the length of the longest line. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=192b8d70dd81ef4262060b2fb9eb6c7e)

```rs
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct ValueReader<B, V> {
    // The underlying BufRead
    buffer: B,
    // The current line being read
    line: String,
    // The current offset into the current line
    index: usize,
    // The type being parsed
    _value_type: PhantomData<V>,
}

impl<B, V> ValueReader<B, V> {
    fn new(b: B) -> Self {
        Self {
            buffer: b,
            line: String::new(),
            index: 0,
            _value_type: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self) -> Option<V>
    where
        V: FromStr,
        V::Err: Debug,
        B: BufRead,
    {
        loop {
            // Check if line is consumed, or the iterator just started
            if self.line.is_empty() {
                let bytes = self.buffer.read_line(&mut self.line).unwrap();
                // Buffer is completely consumed
                if bytes == 0 {
                    return None;
                }
            }

            let unconsumed = self.line[self.index..].trim_start();
            self.index = self.line.len() - unconsumed.len();

            let Some(word) = unconsumed.split_whitespace().next() else {
                // Line is consumed, reset to original state
                self.index = 0;
                self.line.clear();
                continue;
            };
            self.index += word.len();

            return Some(word.parse().unwrap());
        }
    }
}

impl<B, V> Iterator for ValueReader<B, V>
where
    V: FromStr,
    V::Err: Debug,
    B: BufRead,
{
    type Item = V;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.value()
    }
}
```

This could be made more efficient by using `fill_buf` and `consume` to only read one word at a time, shortening the max length of the `String`. It would also be sensible to report errors instead of unwrapping.

Comment: With my edit of the question it should be clear that this does not really answer the question. But it at least answers a big part of the old question!