# Handling streaming iterator as normal iterator by using PhantomData and unsafe

Tags: stream, iterator, rust, unsafe

I know the code below is hacky, but could it be called safe and idiomatic Rust? Is there better way for this?

```
// needs to do 'rustup default nightly' to run under valgrind
// #![feature(alloc_system, global_allocator, allocator_api)]
// extern crate alloc_system;
// use alloc_system::System;
// #[global_allocator]
// static A: System = System;

struct Foo<'a> {
    v: Vec<u8>,
    pos: usize,
    phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a u8>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Foo<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut u8> {
        let r = self.v.get_mut(self.pos);
        if r.is_some() {
            self.pos += 1;
            unsafe { Some(&mut *(r.unwrap() as *mut u8)) }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn reset(&mut self) {
        self.pos = 0;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Foo {
        v: (1..10).collect(),
        pos: 0,
        phantom: std::marker::PhantomData,
    };
    let vp = x.v.as_ptr();

    {
        for i in &mut x {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    }
    {
        x.reset();
    }
    {
        for i in &mut x {
            *i *= *i;
        }
    }
    {
        x.reset();
    }
    {
        for i in &mut x {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    }

    assert!(vp == x.v.as_ptr());
}
```

Write a little bit in the comment, Valgrind told me no leak and the result is as expected under Rust 1.26.0-nightly and 1.25.0.

Related:

- [How do I write an iterator that returns references to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422177/how-do-i-write-an-iterator-that-returns-references-to-itself)
- [Iterator returning items by reference, lifetime issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574741/iterator-returning-items-by-reference-lifetime-issue)

Comment: Whenever writing an `unsafe` block, I *strongly* encourage people to include a comment on the block explaining *why you think the code is actually safe*. That type of information is useful for the people who read the code in the future, and will be useful to any potential answerer. Please [edit] your question to explain why **you** think this code is actually safe

Comment: Thank you for your always prompt response. Talking about  `unsafe`, I have no thought, sorry. I recognize I just try to cheat lifetime checker. valgrind actually reports your `example()` code read invalid.

Comment: There is **no way** to do what you want to do (and believe me, I tried). You must wait for generic associated types and an update of Rust iterators.

Answer (score 2):

This code is **not safe**. The user of the type may choose any lifetime, including `'static`:

```
fn constructor() -> Foo<'static> {
    Foo {
        v: vec![42; 10],
        pos: 0,
        phantom: std::marker::PhantomData,
    }
}

fn example() -> &'static u8 {
    let mut f = constructor();
    f.next().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    println!("example: {}", example());
}
```

Here, `example` returns a reference to a variable that is no longer in scope, accessing invalid memory and subverting the restrictions you must uphold.

---

There's [an example of how you could write this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49684475/155423) with no `unsafe` whatsoever in another Q&A.