# How to return a reference when implementing an iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I would like to return a reference to an owned object that is in a collection (viz., a `Vec`), but I cannot seem to get the lifetimes correct. Here is what I first tried:

```rust
struct StringHolder {
    strings: Vec<String>,
    i: usize,
}

impl Iterator for StringHolder {
    type Item<'a> = &'a String;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.i >= self.strings.len() {
            None
        } else {
            self.i += 1;
            Some(&self.strings[self.i])
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sh = StringHolder { strings: vec![], i: 0 };
    for string in sh {
        println!("{}", string);
    }
}
```

I get an error that `generic associated types are unstable` and `lifetimes do not match type in trait`. I tried a few other iterations, but nothing seemed to work.

I gather that this may not be possible based on some things I've read, but then I can't seem to figure out how `Vec` does it itself. For example, I can use the following to simply iterate over the underlying `Vec` and return a reference on each iteration:

```rust
struct StringHolder {
    strings: Vec<String>,
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a StringHolder {
    type Item = &'a String;
    type IntoIter = ::std::slice::Iter<'a, String>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        (&self.strings).into_iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sh = StringHolder { strings: vec!["A".to_owned(), "B".to_owned()] };
    for string in &sh {
        println!("{}", string);
    }
}
```

So that makes me think it is possible, I just haven't figured out lifetimes yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Iterator` doesn't allow the lifetime of its `Item`s to vary with the lifetime of the `self`, but in your case the items are *stored* in the iterator and share its lifetime, so that's just not going to work. `Vec` does nothing like what you're trying to do. Iterators should be separate from containers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterator lifetime issue when returning references to inner collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788168/iterator-lifetime-issue-when-returning-references-to-inner-collection)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Iterator` trait doesn't include a lifetime for `Item`, which is one of the errors you are seeing. The other alludes to [GATs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) which *was* an unstable Rust feature when this question was originally asked. GATs applied to this example would let you bound the lifetime of an item for each individual call to `next()` instead of all items having the same lifetime. Having said that, the `Iterator` trait is unlikely to change so this more flexible behaviour would have to be a new trait.

Given the design of the `Iterator` trait, you can't have an iterator own its data *and at the same time* have its `Item` be a reference to it. There just isn't a way to express the lifetime.

The way iterators are usually written, in order to have the items be references, is to make them hold a reference to the underlying data. This provides a named lifetime for the data, which can be used on the associated `Item`. `Vec` *sort of* does this, but it's a bit different because `Vec` actually gets its iteration from `slice`.

Your complete example:

```
struct StringHolder {
    strings: Vec<String>,
}

struct StringHolderIter<'a> {
    string_holder: &'a StringHolder,
    i: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for StringHolderIter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.i >= self.string_holder.strings.len() {
            None
        } else {
            self.i += 1;
            Some(&self.string_holder.strings[self.i - 1])
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a StringHolder {
    type Item = &'a str;
    type IntoIter = StringHolderIter<'a>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        StringHolderIter {
            string_holder: self,
            i: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would we do this now that GATs have stabilized?

Comment: @avi I would still do it this way. GATs don't change much here - unless the problem required something like a streaming iterator.

Comment: This was an amazingly helpful response thank you very much!

Comment: That doesn't work for mutable iterators, though. For that, you need to manually transmute `&mut` to `&'a mut`, even though the returned value is technically already a `&'a mut`.