# Create Iterator that yields references to its fields

Tags: rust, iterator, sharedpreferences, lifetime

I would like to define a struct that implements `Iterator` such that the items yielded are references to one of the the struct's fields.

Lets say I have defined my struct like this:

```rust
struct InnerType;
struct MyStruct {
    field: InnerType
}
```

The following does not work because the Associated Type `Item` requires an explicit lifetime parameter:

```rust
impl Iterator for MyStruct {
    type Item = &InnerType;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> { Some(&self.field) }
}
```

Adding a lifetime parameter there doesn't work either because "the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates".

```rust
impl<'a> Iterator for MyStruct {
    type Item = &'a InnerType;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> { Some(&self.field) }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing. What is going on here? Is there some reason(s) *not* to have an iterator which yields items borrowing from itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this *really* what you want? Or would you rather want it so that someone can *request* an iterator over `MyStruct`, the way someone would call `iter()` on a `Vec`?

If that's the case, you're lucky. You just need a *different* struct actually implementing the `Iterator` trait and that struct will contain a reference to `field`.

```rust
struct InnerType;
struct MyStruct {
    field: InnerType
}

struct MyIterator<'a> {
    field: &'a InnerType
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> MyIterator<'a> {
        MyIterator{ field: &self.field }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a InnerType;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> { Some(self.field) }
}

fn main() {
    let foo: InnerType = InnerType{};
    
    let my_struct = MyStruct{ field: foo };
    
    let mut it = my_struct.iter();
    
    let item = it.next();
    
    assert!(item.is_some());
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=795bc0433a3a4e621486ecddf8f0a787

Otherwise, there's some discussions on here already about the issue with "streaming iterators", that is, iterators that return references to items in self.

See, for example, here: [Iterator lifetime issue when returning references to inner collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788168/iterator-lifetime-issue-when-returning-references-to-inner-collection?rq=1)

Now this mentions that Generic Associated Types would be required. And those have now made their way into stable Rust (1.65) but I'm not sure if that means that the standard `Iterator` trait now supports that type of streaming iterator.

Comment: No, it doesn't, and probably never will.