# Rust Lifetimes when implementing Iterator and returning object with reference to Iterator

Tags: rust

I've got a problem with lifetime specifiers in Rust.
I have a type `Foo` that holds a vector of Strings. It should also implement the `Iterator` trait, returning objects that hold a reference to Strings in `Foo`.

*see code example*

What should the lifetime `'?` be? How can I tell the Rust compiler that this works? Or is this entirely impossible or against some of Rust's idioms? What would be the appropriate workaround?

Code example:

```rust
struct Foo {
    strings: Vec<String>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(strings: Vec<String>) -> Self {
        Self { strings }
    }
}

struct Bar<'a> {
    ref: &'a String,
}

impl Iterator for Foo {
    type Item = Bar<'?>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider questioning whether `Foo` is really expected to implement `Iterator` here. If it is just a collection mean to be iterable, `IntoIterator` would be a better trait. Alternatives: implement `IntoIterator` for `Foo` or `&Foo`; add a method which returns an iterator to the inner vector.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, this is not possible in current rust and probably never will [1].
I only see the following workaround.

Create another struct `FooIterator` that implements `Iterator` instead of `Foo` itself and is returned by a `Foo::iter()` method.
This seems to be the common practice.

[1] [Create Iterator that yields references to its fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74711448/create-iterator-that-yields-references-to-its-fields?rq=1)