# How to create slices as `Item`s of a custom iterator

Tags: rust

I tried to play a bit with slices from custom iterators. It seems like I must use lifetime, but I don't always have anything to bound it with

Lets say I have the following code:

```rust
struct FileBlockReader {
    file_reader: BufReader<File>
}

impl FileBlockReader {
    pub fn new(file: File) -> FileBlockReader {
        FileBlockReader {
            file_reader: BufReader::new(file)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to implement iterator on `FileBlockReader` with reads the data by slices of X bytes:

```rust
impl<'a> Iterator for FileBlockReader {
    type Item = &'a [u8];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

I have to specify lifetime to `Item`, but what should I bind it too?
Well the owner of the data is `file_reader` in `FileBlockReader`. But because it is not reference I can't add lifetime specifier to it.

The only way I found that works is converting `File` in the `BufReader` to be reference. Than I can add lifetime specifier to it.
But I want `FileBlockReader` to be the owner of the `File`

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterator lifetime issue when returning references to inner collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788168/iterator-lifetime-issue-when-returning-references-to-inner-collection)

Comment: It's not exactly an inner collection, but it *is* the same underlying issue, and the answers and comments apply.

Comment: Where, exactly, `FileBlockReader` owns the data?

Comment: @SebastianRedl This is not the same issue. The `next()` method here would need to return a reference to a temporary created inside `next()`, which is also impossible, but for a different reason. The `FakeIterator` solution from the answer you linked does not apply here.

Comment: The easiest solution for the problem in this question is to change the item type to `Vec<u8>`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach If the iterator has an internal buffer to read into, it becomes the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, you must be able to bound the `'a` lifetime to something on the type implementing `Iterator`.

There is no way to get this working if you want `Iterator` implemented directly on `FileBlockReader`. You will need to make a separate type for your iterator, like so:

```rust
struct Blocks<'a> {
    reader: &'a mut FileBlockReader,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Blocks<'a> {
    type Item = &'a [u8]

    fn next(&mut self) -> Self::Item {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl FileBlockReader {
    pub fn blocks(&mut self) -> Blocks<'_> {
        Blocks { reader: self }
    }
}
```

This same limitation exists for all the iterators in the standard library. `Vec` does not implement `Iterator`. Rather, you must call the `iter()` method to get an iterator that *borrows* data from the vec.

Comment: `Vec does not implement Iterator. Rather, you must call the iter() method to get an iterator that borrows data from the vec.` - This is an excellent example! Thank you!